# MySQL how join to empty table?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

i'm have SQL query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = 50
WHERE a.something = 'something'
```

AND `a table` is really empty, and so it should be. But table b not empty and have valid result on `b.id = 50`. This query print empty set.

As a result i need:

```
| a.id  | b.id  |
|------ |------ |
| null  | 50    |
```

Comment: You should use right join, Read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: if table 'a' is empty why use a.something='something'? It will provide null result. Besides use either right join or use b left join a

Comment: This is a misuse of `JOIN`.  `JOINs` (whether `LEFT` or not) should state (in `ON`) how the two tables are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the `left` join or do a `right` join:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.something = 'something'
WHERE b.id = 50
```

OR

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM a
RIGHT JOIN b ON b.id = 50
WHERE a.something = 'something'
```

Comment: Your RIGHT JOIN will be converted to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thx, this solution work, im swap not empty table to `from` and empty to left join.